# Symfony2 Guzzle set HTTP request

Tags: php, symfony

I am working in Symfony2 and I try to use Guzzle in one of my tests(PHPUnit) to set some values into my request.

I want to add these into my request:

```
 $string = '{
            "postcode":"XXX-XXX",
            "source_channel":"BU",
            "flow":"ENQUIRY",
            "email_address":"test@test",
            "first_name":"Bob",
            "surname":"White",
            "User-Agent":"Mozilla",
        }';
```

My guzzle code:

```
$client = new \Guzzle\Http\Client();
$post = $client->post('http://127.0.0.1/api/save/details', array(), $string);
$data = $post->send();
```

Error:

```
Guzzle\Http\Exception\ClientErrorResponseException: Client error response
[status code] 404
[reason phrase] Not Found
[url] http://127.0.0.1/api/save/details
```

I am really new to guzzle but it seems straight forward in what I am trying to do. I assume from the error message might be wrong but something is wrong with URL which for a fact I know is good....

Any idea what might be going wrong here?

Comment: Does your action work when using your browser ?

Comment: Did you try to access `http://127.0.0.1/api/save/details` in your browser?

Comment: yes it does work in my browser

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me that there is a typo in the domain part of your url. Try to change

```
'http://127.0.0.1:/api/save/details'
```

to

```
'http://127.0.0.1/api/save/details'
```

Comment: well spoted but thats not the issue i forgot to delete the : because i was trying to use different por to see if it works like :8000